# Mars to Rover on JavaScript. I need to be able to tell a series of commands to the rover and execute them in sequence.

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, javascript-objects

I am working on Mars to Rover program with JavaScript and I already finished iteration 1 that allows my rover to move to all directions in 2 dimensions (x,y). Now it comes iteration #2 where I need to be able to tell a series of commands to the rover and execute them in sequence.

Please give me some insights of how you would do iteration 2.

This is my current code:

```js
// --------- Mars Rover Kata: Iteration #1  ------------ \\


// ------------------- User Experience using Console --------- \\
var promptSay = "Play with the Console!\nW = UP \nS = DOWN \nD = RIGHT \nA = LEFT";

var gridEdge = "You can\'go there! \n\nPlease notice that you are playing with an imaginary grid and the farest you can go is 9 steps";

var wrongInput = "---WRONG INPUT!--- Please use a correct input i. e. : \nW = UP \nS = DOWN \nD = RIGHT \nA = LEFT";

// Object Definition: (Vars inside a Var , may have functions)  \\




var AJRover = {
    position : [0, 0],
    invalidInput: function(notright) {     // Notification for invalid Input
        alert(notright);
        this.move(prompt(wrongInput));
    },
    invalidKey: function(message) {       // Notification if you reach grid's edge
        alert(message);
        this.move(prompt(promptSay));
    },
    move: function(moveRover) {                       //Directions
        switch(moveRover.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'w':
                this.goDirection("up");
                break;
            case 's':
                this.goDirection("down");
                break;
            case 'd':
                this.goDirection("right");
                break;
            case 'a':
                this.goDirection('left');
                break;
            default:
              this.invalidInput(wrongInput);
            }

        },
    goDirection: function(direction) {      //Directions Functions
        switch(direction) {
            case 'up':
                if (this.position[1] >= -9 && (this.position[1] + 1) <= 9) {
                    this.position[1]++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.invalidKey(gridEdge);
                    break;
                }

            case 'down':
                if (this.position[1] <= 9  &&  (this.position[1] -1 ) >= -9) {  // this needs to go back and stop at -9
                    this.position[1]--;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.invalidKey(gridEdge);
                    break;
                }

            case 'right':
                if (this.position[0] >= -9 && (this.position[0] + 1) <= 9) {
                    this.position[0]++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.invalidKey(gridEdge);
                    break;
                }

            case 'left':
                if (this.position[0] <= 9 && (this.position[0] -1) >= -9) {
                    this.position[0]--;
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.invalidKey(gridEdge);
                    break;
                }

        }
    }

};

// ---- object END ----- \\\
// 1- This function calls the object move (this.move)
// 2- Sends the alert to prompts the var promptSay
// 3- Expects input to decide the output

while (true) {                                   //This code block allows user move the rover on mars by interacting with console
    var entry = prompt(promptSay);
    AJRover.move(entry);
    console.log('You are now at position: ', AJRover.position);
}
```

Comment: The title of this question is priceless!

Comment: It is not clear from your question what exactly are you asking and what type of answer you expect. Is this a valid answer to you? : "Store the commands in an array and then iterate through the array executing one command after another."

Comment: @Matey once you execute this code the user has to write a letter "w" for up "s" is down "d" is right and "a" means go left. My program is only reading one character , so I am only able to go step by step on the grid.  What I want to do is to write "wsdawwwwd" or any other series of commands and that will move my rover from coordinates [0,0] to [1,4] as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browse environment, this cannot be done by interacting with console.

What you have to do is utilize event listeners. Here is an example how it could be done by binding them on document body.

```
const W_KEY = 119;
const A_KEY = 97;
const S_KEY = 115;
const D_KEY = 100;

document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  let entry = null;

  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case W_KEY:
      entry = "w";
      break;
    case A_KEY:
      entry = "a";
      break;
    case S_KEY:
      entry = "s";
      break;
    case D_KEY:
      entry = "d";
      break;
  }

  if(entry) {
    console.log("Key " + entry + " was pressed!");

    AJRover.move(key);
  }

}
```

Comment: as I told to Matey "once you execute this code the user has to write a letter "w" for up "s" is down "d" is right and "a" means go left. My program is only reading one character , so I am only able to go step by step on the grid. What I want to do is to write "wsdawwwwd" or any other series of commands and that will move my rover from coordinates [0,0] to [1,4] as example. "

Comment: @AlejandroJimenez I rewrote my answer according to new spec.

Comment: Browser environment has no console you can work with in this care. You can create a text element to emulate it.